# How to implement compareTo in a generic method that takes a generic array as argument?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to implement a method, that, given a generic array, and two index values, slice the array, and find the largest element between the two given numbers.

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(T[] array, int firstIndx, int secondIndx) {        //requires comparable
    T maxElement = array[0];      //8
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

    for (int i = firstIndx; i < secondIndx - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = firstIndx + 1; j < secondIndx; j++) {
            if (array[i].compareTo(array[j]) > 0) {
                maxElement = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = maxElement;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    return maxElement;
}
```

But for an arrays of ints [8, 4, 6, 20, 1], is swapping correctly just the first two elements, giving me the wrong maximum elements. What's wrong with the code ?

Comment: With what parameters do you call your function? Also consider removing the `intellj-idea` and `javafx` tags as they seem to be unrelated.

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that I typed the wrong tags. Btw I call the function passing the array and not slicing it at all, so with the firstIndx = 0 and the secondIndx= 4, since the problem is in the bubble sort

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Also if you aim is to find the maximum element, you should only need one loop across the array.

Comment: I don't know how to debug the code. Yeah I know, if I have to find just the max element, the method works, but I want understand why the bubble sorting is giving me this strange output.

Comment: Its nor really `bubble sort` you do here. In bubble sort you compare the `i` and the `i+1` element. Also your `maxElement` is just a temp variable that has the value from your last swap operation. -- For debugging check this [tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html)

Comment: You should create methods with a clear purpose, not a mixture of different tasks. No-one would ever expect that a method called `max` that returns a value will also modify the specified array. A method that sorts a slice should be named `sort` and it doesn’t need to return a value (like [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-int-int-)), as reading out the last element of the slice afterward is trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your sort. The first is that you're using `firstIndx` and `secondIndx`, but based on how your code is structured, it's treating that second number as if it were the second index *minus 1*.

The second issue is that your inner loop is starting back at `firstIndx` every time, which breaks the bubble sort.  It needs to start at `i`.

Try this modification to your for loops:

```
for (int i = firstIndx; i <= secondIndx - 1; i++) { // Notice the "<=".
    for (int j = i + 1; j <= secondIndx; j++) { // j starts at i
    // ... existing bubble sort code goes here
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I failed to mention that your approach won't find the max if the max is already in its sorted position.  You should just grab the max from `array[secondIndx]` after you're done sorting.

---

As an aside, `firstIndx` is a pretty bad variable name.  It's only one letter more to write it out in full: `firstIndex`.

Comment: Counterexample: `max(new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5},0,4);` -> result would be `1`

Comment: Good catch.  I was addressing the sorting issue, and not the max-finding issue.   @WebStormer, check out my edit.